# ggtern error (in `stat_density_tern()`: unused argument (z.range = z.range) )

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggtern

I try to reproduce a ggtern code from this post: [Ternary plot - scaling opacity across groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57175114/ternary-plot-scaling-opacity-across-groups)

```
  library(ggtern)
  set.seed(1234)
  df <- data.frame(X = c(runif(150, 0.7, 1),runif(50, 0, 0.3)),
                   Y = c(runif(150, 0, 0.3),runif(50, 0, 0.3)),
                   Z = c(runif(150, 0, 0.5),runif(50, 0.5, 1)),
                   D = c(rep("A", 150), rep("B", 50)))


  # ternary plot 
  ggtern(df, aes(x = X,y = Y, z = Z, color = D)) +
    stat_density_tern(aes(alpha = ..level.., fill = D), 
                      geom = 'polygon', 
                      bins = 10,
                      color = "grey",bdl=0.005) +
    geom_point(alpha = 0.5) +
    scale_colour_manual(values = c("tomato3", "turquoise4"))``
```

And I get the following error:

Warning messages:
1: Removed 3 rows containing non-finite values (StatDensityTern).
2: Computation failed in `stat_density_tern()`:
unused argument (z.range = z.range)

I don't understand what caused the computational problem with the unused argument, which seems to fail to draw the density contour around points. 
[image]

Can someone figure out what the problem is? Thanks.

Comment: This still might be a bug in the code. The example code in the help also does not work. Here is contact information: http://www.ggtern.com

Comment: This is a bug from the recent submission to cran getting ggtern functioning again with ggplot2 v3.3.X. I'll fix and resubmit, sorry about this.

Comment: actually, what version of ggtern are you running?